# How to add a subpath to root url on Apache

Tags: apache

I'm using Apache 2.4 (on a Drupal 7/Docker project).

I want my all my site pages to map from `/var/www/html` to `http://domain/foo/` (eg: `/var/www/html/1/2/3/` to `http://domain/foo/1/2/3/`)

I prefer to avoid using `.htacess` and only apache conf file

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName foo_name

    # Try 1
    Alias /foo /var/www/html

    # Try 2
    Redirect "/" "/foo/"

    <Directory /var/www/html>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            AllowOverride None
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from All

            # Try 3
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /foo
```

---

To do so I tried :

- [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) : `Alias /foo /var/www/html` so I can access to my front page with `http://domain/foo/` but it doesn't work on `http://domain/foo/1/2/3/`). And also it's just a one way redirection.
- [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) `Redirect "/" "/foo/"` : I did not worked on my bowser I try to acces to `http://domain/foo/` but I got this url (almost infinite loop) `http://domain/foo/foo/foo/foo/foo/foo/foo/foo/foo/`...
- [RewriteBase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html) : `RewriteBase /foo` but it doesn't work probably because I need to match it with htacess on subdirectory.
- [Most advanced rewriting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) : I saw a lot of them on StackOverflock/ServerFault but it did'nt seem appropriate for my problem (I never use before regex PCRE, harder to adapt). Moreover I should [avoid using rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working like that (alias + RewriteRule) :

```
    Alias /foo /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>

            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            AllowOverride None
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from All
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```